# vs code not showing errors and workspace problem in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, github, compiler-errors

All expected error aren't shown in vs code. I'm using flutter and there is another problem appear after every change i make which is "You are modifying a file outside of your open folders" and i think it might be related to the first problem

So i've two problems:

1. vs code is not showing errors, not even a red line
2. every simple change i make shows me the message "You are modifying a file outside of your open             folders"

I didn't use vs code for two months and i end up with this problem today. Note that the code is runnable as it is without changes.

I checked flutter doctor and everything is fine.

Comment: did you try to resintall the dart and flutter extensions?